# Remove rows from 1 csv from another

Tags: powershell

I have a list of hosts/computers in `list.csv` with a `host name` column. Some of them have not been logged into in a while so I want to remove all rows that contain an out of date computer record.

I can get all computers in the domain that have not been logged into in 90 days(ish) using the code below, however I want to take that list of computers and compare them to `list.csv`, removing matching computers from `list.csv`.

I've tried now for a while with other articles and `Import-CSV` etc, but can't crack it.

```
import-module activedirectory  
$domain = "contoso.local"  
$DaysInactive = 90  
$time = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive)) 

# Get all AD computers with lastLogonTimestamp less than our time 
Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $time} -Properties     LastLogonTimeStamp | 

# Output hostname and lastLogonTimestamp into CSV 
select-object Name | export-csv "C:\users\bicard\Desktop\allComputerslistFromDomainLookup.csv" -notypeinformation
```

Comment: You can read the list of computers in a var and then use the operator `contains`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just posting I see this is @JPBlanc's tip.

```
$DaysInactive = 90  
$OutDate = (Get-Date).Adddays(-($DaysInactive)) 

# Get all AD computers with lastLogonTimestamp less than our time 
$OutDated = Get-ADComputer -Filter {LastLogonTimeStamp -lt $OutDate} -Properties LastLogonTimeStamp | 
  select-object -ExpandProperty Name 

Import-Csv List.csv | 
  Where { $OutDated -notcontains $($_.'host name'} |
    Export-csv NewList.csv -notypeinformation
```

Comment: Thanks.    Ive tried that.   The $outdated does contain a list of computer names however they still included in the newlist.csv.   It looks like the section.        Where { $OutDated -notcontains $($_.'host name'}         is not biting.

Comment: @Confuseis In the above code, replace `select-object Name` with `Select-Object -ExpandProperty Name`, or specify `$OutDated.Name`.  `Select-Object` cmdlet returns an object with the listed properties by default.  `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` is necessary to return an array that just contains the values of the selected property.